# Are empty IP fragments invalid?

Tags: udp, ip, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I've been trying to diagnose an issue with dropped UDP-IP datagrams, and one thing I'm noticing with Wireshark is that we're occasionally getting a datagram that Wireshark doesn't consider a packet (it won't do its trick of automagically reassembling the fragmented UDP datagram into the last fragment's packet).

Upon closer inspection, it looks like the last fragment of these packets that Wireshark doesn't like is a data-less fragment of length 60 (the minimum). What appears to be happening is that our stack's IP fragmentation algorithm, when the datagram fits into fragments *exactly* (its size is a multiple of 1480), rather than clearing the "last packet" flag on that last completely full packet, instead sends one last empty fragment with the "last packet" flag cleared.

[image]

Obviously this is weird enough to throw off Wireshark. But how wrong is it? Is this wrong enough to be causing receiving stacks (in this case some version of Windows I think) to discard the IP fragments? Is this actually a violation of the IPv4 standards for fragmented packets?

Fortunately, we have the sources for this IP stack, so we can fix it if we need to.

Answer (score 2):

*How wrong is it?*  I think that's a somewhat difficult question to answer definitively. From a technical standpoint, I don't think it's wrong per se, as it doesn't seem to violate any RFC's for fragment reassembly, but it's certainly inefficient and there might be mechanisms in place to drop fragments of this sort.  Perusing the various RFC's, I've come across the following relevant or related RFC's:

- [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791): Internet Protocol
- [RFC 815](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc815): IP Datagram Reassembly Algorithms
- [RFC 1858](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1858): Security Considerations for IP Fragment Filtering
- [RFC 3128](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3128): Protection Against a Variant of the Tiny Fragment Attack

There may be others.  These RFC's don't address this particular case; however, they do address reassembly and security considerations for other cases, which leads me to believe that the prudent thing to do would be to modify your IP stack, if possible, in order to avoid this inefficient transmission of an empty datagram.  Not only will you improve efficiency, you'll avoid any potential problems that could arise from this case.  Considering how many devices and IP stacks there are out there, I'd say it's a bit risky to leave the implementation as it is, but that's just my opinion.

As for why Wireshark doesn't reassemble the fragmented datagrams, that's simple.  The IP dissector ([packet-ip.c](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ip.c;h=e739a27b28cb382196f95ad4d609c4f42a4b5663;hb=HEAD#l2222)) currently expects at least 1 byte of payload.  Here's the relevant code snippet from that file:

```
  /* If ip_defragment is on, this is a fragment, we have all the data
   * in the fragment, and the header checksum is valid, then just add
   * the fragment to the hashtable.
   */
  save_fragmented = pinfo->fragmented;
  if (ip_defragment && (iph->ip_off & (IP_MF|IP_OFFSET)) &&
      iph->ip_len > hlen &&
      tvb_bytes_exist(tvb, offset, iph->ip_len - hlen) &&
      ipsum == 0) {
    ipfd_head = fragment_add_check(&ip_reassembly_table, tvb, offset,
                                   pinfo,
                                   iph->ip_proto ^ iph->ip_id ^ src32 ^ dst32 ^ pinfo->vlan_id,
                                   NULL,
                                   (iph->ip_off & IP_OFFSET) * 8,
                                   iph->ip_len - hlen,
                                   iph->ip_off & IP_MF);

    next_tvb = process_reassembled_data(tvb, offset, pinfo, "Reassembled IPv4",
                                        ipfd_head, &ip_frag_items,
                                        &update_col_info, ip_tree);
  } else {
      ...
  }
```

As a simple test, I tweaked the last fragment of a two-part packet such that it contained 0 bytes.  I then made the following change to the IP dissector:

```
  iph->ip_len >= hlen &&
```

After recompiling Wireshark, the packet was reassembled.  So, I believe this simple change would allow Wireshark to successfully reassemble fragments of the type you have now where the last fragment contains no data.  While I think your IP stack should still be modified to avoid sending these empty fragments, I also think in keeping with [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) that Wireshark should be modified to handle this case, albeit with an *"Expert Info"* added to indicate this strange empty fragment so developers can be alerted to their inefficient implementations.  To that end, I would recommend that you file a [Wireshark enhancement bug request](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) so Wireshark will be able to reassemble such fragments.

Comment: Well...if that indeed is the problem with the packets getting dropped (I hope to find that out during my sim time tomorrow), I kind of prefer it this way, because I *never* would have noticed this if Wireshark hadn't been failing to reassemble the packets. Perhaps it should at least mark them a different (warning?) color to indicate some stacks may have a problem with them.

Comment: I  understand, which is why I suggested a Wireshark "Expert Info" be added if this change is to be made to Wireshark.  The "Expert Info" mechanism is used to alert on many things.  I guess it depends on whether this is technically wrong or not as to whether Wireshark should be modified or not.  If it is wrong, then Wireshark should behave as it does today, but if not, then Wireshark should reassemble the fragments.  While it's certainly inefficient, I can't find anywhere where this is *technically* wrong though.

Comment: Obviously it took a bit longer (things came up, as they always do), but it looks like the Windows stack (Windows 10 I believe) is indeed throwing these fragments away. The switch passes them on (I'm seeing them on a tap btwn the switch and the Windows rack) but I'm not getting a response from the app running on the Windows box like I do for all other fragmented UDP packets. I suppose its also possible one of their switches in their rack is tossing them, but its definitely making it past our switch, but not into their Windows box.